# Join predicate order

Tags: mysql, join, database-design, relational-database

I'm always be amused and confused(at same time) whenever I have been to asked prepare and run `Join` query on Sql Console.

And the cause of most confusion is mainly based upon the fact whether/or not the **ordering** of join predicate hold any importances in Join results.

Example.

```
SELECT  "zones"."name", "ip_addresses".*
    FROM  "ip_addresses"
    INNER JOIN  "zones" ON "zones"."id" = "ip_addresses"."zone_id"
    WHERE  "ip_addresses"."resporg_accnt_id" = 1
      AND  "zones"."name" = 'us-central1'
    LIMIT  1;
```

Given the sql query, the Join predicate look like this.

`... INNER JOIN "zones" ON "zones"."id" = "ip_addresses"."zone_id" WHERE "ip_addresses"."resporg_accnt_id"`

Now, would it make any difference in term of **performance** of Join as well as the authenticity of the obtained result. If happen to change the predicate to look like this

`... INNER JOIN "zones" ON  "ip_addresses"."zone_id" = "zones"."id" WHERE "ip_addresses"."resporg_accnt_id"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The predicate order won't make a performance difference in your case, a simple equality condition, but personally I like to place the columns from the table I'm `JOIN`ing to on the LHS of each `ON` condition

```
SELECT ...
  FROM ip_addresses ia

  JOIN zones z
    ON z.id = ia.zone_id 

 WHERE ...
```

The optimiser can use any index available on these columns during the `JOIN` and I find it easier to visualise this way.

Any additional conditions also tend to be on columns of the table being `JOIN`ed to and I find again this reads better when this table is consistently on the LHS

---

**Not quite the same**, but I did see a case where performance was affected by the choice of column to isolate

I think the JOIN looked something like

```
SELECT ...
  FROM table_a a

  JOIN table_b b
    ON a.id = b.id - 1
```

Changing this to

```
SELECT ...
  FROM table_a a

  JOIN table_b b
    ON b.id = a.id + 1
```

allowed the optimiser to use an index on `b.id`, but presumably at the cost of an index on `a.id`

I suspect this kind of query might need analysing on a case by case basis

---

**Furthermore**, I would probably switch your table order round too and write your original query:

```
SELECT z.name,
       ia.* 
  FROM zones z 

  JOIN ip_addresses ia
    ON ia.zone_id = z.id
   AND ia.resporg_accnt_id = 1

 WHERE z.name = 'us-central1' 
 LIMIT 1
```

Conceptually, you are saying "Start with the 'us-central1' zone and fetch me all the ip_addresses associated with a resporg_accnt_id of 1"

Check the `EXPLAIN` plans if you want to verify that there is no difference in your case

Comment: I really thought you didn't answer the question since you introduced another concept as if it's directly contradicting your answer, which makes me think that you didn't really answered, but just introduced another concept altogether. 

Basically you're saying "It won't make a difference in this case...but I like to write my queries this way.." when in fact you are saying "The ordering of join predicate won't make a difference but I like to write my queries this way..". The latter sounds clearer at least for me. Just saying.. PS: the way you write your code is really efficient though.

Comment: @GellieAnn Thanks for the tips, I have clarified a touch, and added a case that gave me pause before committing to a  'no performance difference in all cases' answer

Comment: Very nice. It's clearer now and thank you also for an example where the order of the predicate affects the performance. I've been meaning to ask such but didn't because my comment would be too long then. PS: I'll just comment the link I found here, stating that on most cases, the order of the predicate isn't really important, instead of posting another answer.: https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/2008/02/29/60542/